# What does a 交番 look like?

Tags: translation

I know the dictionary definition of 交番{こうばん}, but I've absolutely no idea of what one actually looks like in real life. So, if someone were to tell me the general location of one, what characteristics would I be looking for to identify the exact location?

Comment: I think this is borderline off-topic, but I'll leave it.  Usually they say `交番` on them, so they're not hard to spot.  Also usually on street corners, corner of a building, etc.

Comment: @istrasci Are they like a police box in London? Or more substantial? Is it like 2 or 3 guys? Or more like 10 guys? In my many year stay in Tokyo, I never noticed a 交番 in Ebisu, Hiroo, Roppongi, or Azabu-juban. Nor, anywhere in Akasaka that I remember. So, are they only identified by the word "交番"?

Comment: I've never been to London, so I don't know.  I lived in Osaka for two years and saw them all over the place.  I think the number of staff in them depends on the actual location and actual 交番 density of the area.  For example, in the heart of 梅田 there were tons of 交番, so each one probably only had 4-5 staff in it.

Comment: @istrasci I never, even once, said ">ah. that is a 交番". But, I also never asked to be shown one and also rarely left a small region of Tokyo. Maybe there were not many there.  I guess the answer is "A 交番 is where ever it says '交番'". Otherwise, there is no uniformity.

Comment: [Here's one in Azabu/Roppongi](https://www.google.com/maps/@35.663478,139.732033,3a,24.7y,60.04h,88.38t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sscy34sR6UBPngL-g2TULxw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1?hl=en).  Searching [Tokyo in Google Maps for 「交番」](https://www.google.com/maps/search/%E4%BA%A4%E7%95%AA/@35.6555777,139.741621,13.19z?hl=en)

Comment: Off-topic and could've been solved in a simple Google image search.

Comment: @Kuri The English def of "交番" is not only what it does, but also what it looks like. So, your saying to do a Google image search for "交番" begs the question of whether Japanese/English can always be translated. Often, it cannot. Not knowing what a 交番 looks like does not allow for transliteration.

Comment: These should be enough examples: http://image.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=top_ga1_sa&p=%E4%BA%A4%E7%95%AA

Comment: @David_W. Sorry if I'm being dense, but I don't get your point. Searching for 「交番」 in Google Images has nothing to do with Japanese/English translation. Why wouldn't you look at the picture of a 交番 instead of asking other people to describe it to you? If your point in asking the question was to get some sort of "visual translation", I'm afraid this is not the correct place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be solved by a simple image search for 交番

Comment: This question is asking what a particular object is. It has nothing to do with grammar, phonetics, semantics or pragmatics of the Japanese language.  The only way to interpret it as a question on the language is to interpret it as a request for translation or "dictionary lookup", both of which are offtopic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E4%BA%A4%E7%95%AA&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI39ij_uSBxwIVwpuUCh2-kA2I&biw=1920&bih=955

Look for huts inside town and you will find them.